Laravel API returning 200 with empty body
I was working on a API in Laravel. I don't know what I did wrong but it keeps returning 200 OK but without any data.
this is api.php :
Route::get('/offre/jobs', [OffreController::class, 'getAllJobs']); 

this is my offerController :
 //this will only return job type offers
 public function getAllJobs()
 {
     $offres = Offre::where('type', 'job')->get();
     return $offres;
 }

this is my Offer model :
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Offre extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'type',
    'employmentType',
    'workplace',
    'description',
     ...
];

Whenever I try with my client (Thunder) it keeps returning 200 with empty body. I do know that I have data in my database that matches my query.

->getAll() ? try ->get()

@ericmp same thing.

Well, I don't see any error in the code you provided, are you sure you are connecting to the correct database, you have all the migrations and there are, in fact, any rows in the table that match the criteria?

@AdrianKokot all of my other api's are working fine.. I don't really know whats wrong.

try dd the $offres to make sure that the request is reaching the route.

don't know why but I removed /offer/jobs to /onlyjob works for me now.
I don't have any other api with same route to /offer/jobs by the way.
